# Is there any way to test WCF service instance management process?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

It's known that WCF services could be instantiated in several different modes (`PerCall`, `PerSession`, `Single` instance context modes). Often developers implement service as a singleton. Speaking about IIS hosted WCF services, is there any way to research how many instances of the service were created, track theirs lifetime to compare different approaches to implementation, performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any way to research how many instances of the service were
>   created, track theirs lifetime

I can think of two approaches:

1. The [IInstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx) extension point enables you to directly manage the service instance lifetime through the `GetInstance()` and  `ReleaseInstance()` methods. You could create a custom implementation of this extension to do the measurements you are requesting (but it would also have to correctly create the service instances). **This would give very accurate measurements.** Note that `InstanceContextMode.Single` does not actually use an `IInstanceProvider` implementation. The singleton is passed directly into the ServiceHost constructor. So `IInstanceProvider` will only give you `PerCall` and `PerSession` information.
2. The [ServiceModel Service Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731087.aspx) provide many of the stats that you are looking for such as number of [Instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733922.aspx) and [Call Duration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734714.aspx). **These counters are quick to configure and in many cases are more than good enough to see the performance difference between instancing models.** Note these counters are really looking at the ServiceHost's InstanceContext count and not the actual service instance count. There is usually a one to one mapping between InstanceContext and service instance. However If you are using the WCF extension of a Dependency Injection engine like Unity or Castle Windsor they are providing an IInstanceProvider implementation which allows you to change the one to one mapping.

If you go #1 there are many example `IInstanceProvider` implementations on the web, but I would start with 
[Carlos Figueira's Blog – IInstanceProvider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/31/wcf-extensibility-iinstanceprovider.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check WCF Message Inspectors. Look at this http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Capturing-WCF-Request-d168060d

Using Message Inspectors you can get the detail abt request lifetime, request counter, Capturing a dump when any WCF operation is taking more than the specified number of seconds.
I think this will help you out.

Comment: A message inspector can measure call duration, but it won't tell you anything about the service instance that actually handled the call or when the service instance was created/released.